# How to remove ajax loader in my code

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, prototype-js

How to remove ajax loader in my code. I want to disable the loader only

```
function changeValue(url, attribute,coulmnAttr,value){
    var url = url + '?attribute=' + attribute + '&attributeValue=' + value + '&coulmnAttr=' + coulmnAttr;
    new Ajax.Request(url, {
        method: 'get',
        asynchronous: false
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the below Code & its Done

```
Element.hide('loading_mask_loader');
```